# Remembering history between sessions in Inferior Emacs Lisp Mode

Tags: comint, desktop, history-variables

I can't make Emacs remember the history for `*ielm*` buffers between sessions.  As far as I can tell, such history is recorded in the buffer-local variable `comint-input-ring`.  Therefore I have added the following expression to my init file:

```
(setq desktop-locals-to-save
    (append desktop-locals-to-save
            '((comint-input-ring . 50))))
```

It doesn't work.  I know that the `desktop` package is working because Emacs remembers the global variables that I have added to `desktop-globals-to-save` in my init file.

--

EDIT: `savehist` does not work either.  I suppose that is because `comint-input-ring` is a buffer-local variable.

Comment: No time now to check why it might not work for desktop. But you can try using `savehist.el` and adding this variable to the list of vars to save.

Comment: Thanks, Drew, but I had thought about `savehist` already (sorry for not mentioning it). As far as I could see, it was for global variables only, whilst `comint-input-ring` is buffer-local.  Now, I have tried it anyway, without success.

Comment: WARNING:  The following solution is *blasphemy*!!!!  Comment out inside `comint.el` the following two lines of code:  `(put 'comint-input-ring 'permanent-local t)` and `(make-local-variable 'comint-input-ring)`.  Then, add `comint-input-ring` to `desktop-locals-to-save`.  Finally, re-byte-compile the applicable files, restart Emacs and enjoy living life to the fullest.

Answer (score 9):

You can save the buffer-local value of `comint-input-ring` in a global variable when an `*ielm*` buffer is killed and restore it in `inferior-emacs-lisp-mode-hook`:

```
;; global copy of the buffer-local variable
(defvar ielm-comint-input-ring nil)

(defun set-ielm-comint-input-ring ()
  ;; create a buffer-local binding of kill-buffer-hook
  (make-local-variable 'kill-buffer-hook)
  ;; save the value of comint-input-ring when this buffer is killed
  (add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook #'save-ielm-comint-input-ring)
  ;; restore saved value (if available)
  (when ielm-comint-input-ring
    (message "Restoring comint-input-ring...")
    (setq comint-input-ring ielm-comint-input-ring)))

(defun save-ielm-comint-input-ring ()
  (message "Saving comint-input-ring...")
  (setq ielm-comint-input-ring comint-input-ring))

(require 'ielm)
(add-hook 'inferior-emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'set-ielm-comint-input-ring)
```

Now you should be able to add `ielm-comint-input-ring` to `savehist-additional-variables` to get the behavior you want. (I tested this approach; you should be able to use `desktop-locals-to-save` too, though.)

Comment: You should use the `LOCAL` argument to `add-hook`, rather than manually calling `make-local-variable` on `kill-buffer-hook`. The latter could cause problems when subsequently trying to add callbacks to the hook globally.

Comment: I was very pleased to find that this worked for `inf-mongo` as well (or, presumably, any other mode that uses `comint`)

That is so helpful, and also taught me a little more elisp... thanks!

Comment: Add `(add-hook 'savehist-save-hook (lambda () (and (get-buffer "*ielm*") (kill-buffer "*ielm*"))))` to make it save the latest history in your `*ielm*` buffer in case you don't explicitly kill that buffer before exiting emacs.